# How would one (formally) describe being socially able to say something because of membership in a certain group?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

How would one formally describe being socially able to say something otherwise considered derogatory on the basis of one's membership of the group towards which the purported derogation would be directed?  For example, "I don't like Chinese food—it's OK, I can say that because I'm Chinese."

TV-Tropes terms this phenomenon "N-Word Privileges", but I (obviously) wouldn't say that in any kind of formal setting.

Comment: misplaced political correctness.  Bending over backwards to demonstrate an anti-racist stance.  But look, disliking a national cuisine has nothing to do with racism.

Comment: You should tread carefully here as your example may be seen as _betrayal_ depending on the context. You can be [self-deprecating](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/self-deprecating) but that only means you can say something derogatory of yourself, not a group to which you belong.

Comment: **Social privilege** : [wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_privilege)

Answer (score 1):

It's a *[dispensation](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dispensation)*, an exemption from what's usually a rule, norm or requirement.